# w3wp.exe consume more cpu usages with silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, w3wp

i have a Silverlight application on my local pc it's working perfect as well working perfect on our staging server. but when i deploy on client server w3wp.exe takes 25% of cpu usages while requesting from browser. After first request approx 1 to 1.5 hour it will not responding after that it's work as normal as expectation. i have also try to deploy simple silverlight applicaton like click on button and show test message.that also not work. after that i am put a simple html page like print "hello world" without silverlight object it's work perfect.

Comment: i have restart the server, it seams problem solve but as talk with client he says we already restart the server befor 2 days.

Comment: @ chirag Are you using Microsoft Windows Server 2003-based computer that has Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 installed?

Comment: No,Hosting server is Server 2008 R2 and IIS-7,My local machine is Windows 8.1